# List available updates but do not install them

Tags: apt

I want my cron-run reporting script to notify me in case there are updates for my packages. Is the a way to make `apt-get` give me the list of available updates but don't do anything more?

Answer (score 319):

## apt

For modern versions of `apt` there is a specific switch for this:

`apt list --upgradable`

## apt-get

For the old `apt-get` command the `-u` switch shows a list of packages that are available for upgrade:

```
# apt-get -u upgrade --assume-no
```

From the [`apt-get` man page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/apt-get):

> **-u
>
> --show-upgraded**  Show upgraded packages; Print out a list of all packages that are to be upgraded. Configuration Item: APT::Get::Show-Upgraded.
>  
> **--assume-no**  Automatic "no" to all prompts. <== To prevent it from starting to install

Comment: I was hoping this could be done without root

Comment: If you type "Y" and press Enter, this command _will_ install updates. I would definitely recommend to add "-s", otherwise this answer is misleading

Comment: This is a *very* wrong answer because (without additional options) the command waits for input and if the user enters the wrong input, the package are installed, *which modifies the system* which is not what the OP wants (just happened on my system)

Comment: And btw: `-u` is a default option of `apt-get`

Comment: @ThorSummoner '-s' will do what you want & works without root

Comment: @nevelis Ah and your comment is reflected in this answer too, perfect! http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/86335/61349

Comment: I prefer the first option because does not require sudo. The second does.

Comment: `apt list --upgradable` is not an equivalent of `apt-get -u upgrade --assume-no` .. the former will only respect UPgrades, no downgrades, while the latter does respect downgrades - i would consider the latter to be the better universal option

Comment: On my Debian9, the "apt list --upgradeable" command isn't recognised. Try "apt list --upgradable" instead. Not sure if that's a typo or just a difference between Debian9 and other systems.

Comment: There isn't a parameter `--assume-no` in [apt-get man page](https://linux.die.net/man/8/apt-get); instead, there is a similar parameter `--trivial-only`

Comment: `apt list --upgradable` is not well suited for a cron-job:
1) It will emit a warning about its "unstable" API and therefore
2) it will always produce output and generate mails even if there are no packages to  upgrade

Answer (score 72):

```
apt-get --just-print upgrade
```

Is not read that easily, below is a perl one liner to parse apt-get's output:

```
apt-get --just-print upgrade 2>&1 | perl -ne 'if (/Inst\s([\w,\-,\d,\.,~,:,\+]+)\s\[([\w,\-,\d,\.,~,:,\+]+)\]\s\(([\w,\-,\d,\.,~,:,\+]+)\)? /i) {print "PROGRAM: $1 INSTALLED: $2 AVAILABLE: $3\n"}'
```

This should output something like:

```
PROGRAM: grub-pc INSTALLED: 1.99-21ubuntu3.1 AVAILABLE: 1.99-21ubuntu3.9
```

Hopefully it will help someone else,

Comment: just for the laugh:   apt-get -s upgrade| awk -F'[][() ]+' '/^Inst/{printf "Prog: %s\tcur: %s\tavail: %s\n", $2,$3,$4}'

Comment: It could also be much more nice looking, if use `column` like this: `apt-get --just-print upgrade 2>&1 | perl -ne 'if (/Inst\s([\w,\-,\d,\.,~,:,\+]+)\s\[([\w,\-,\d,\.,~,:,\+]+)\]\s\(([\w,\-,\d,\.,~,:,\+]+)\)? /i) {print "PROGRAM: $1 INSTALLED: $2 AVAILABLE: $3\n"}' | column -s " " -t`

Comment: @AntonioK Looks great!

Comment: I'm afraid this Perl-code will hack my machine... ;)

Comment: @AntonioK How do you sort the names of the programs alphabetically?

Comment: @Richie Copy the output and paste into something easier to sort.

Answer (score 40):

Another option, inspired by enzotib :

`aptitude search '~U' | wc -l`

This command will use aptitude to output the new packages and then wc to just count the lines.

On a sidenote, I found that enzotib's solution without the single quotes around the `~U` didn't work for me. (Wheezy, ZSH, aptitude 0.6.8.2)

**Update :**

With the new apt you can do:

`apt list --upgradeable`

Comment: Nice with this solution is that you do not need sudo/root.

Answer (score 31):

The easiest is:

`apt list --upgradeable`

Comment: does not work on mint.

Comment: It's a shame this doesn't return different exit codes depending on whether there are upgrades available or not. Would have been nice to able to use this in a script.

Answer (score 21):

You can run

```
aptitude -F%p --disable-columns search ~U
```

or the undocumented

```
/usr/lib/update-notifier/apt-check -p; echo
```

Another method using an `apt-get` simulation:

```
apt-get -s dist-upgrade | awk '/^Inst/ { print $2 }'
```

Comment: This aptitude command worked great for me and did not require root

Comment: apt-get -s dist-upgrade works good too and has same output when you pipe it through that awker

Comment: thank you!  this got out of quite a bit of dependency hell.  was trying to `dist-upgrade` but not lose some packages so needed to use `aptitude`.  `aptitude install $(apt-get -s dist-upgrade | awk '/^Inst/ { print $2 }')` did the trick!

Answer (score 14):

```
apt-get update && apt-get -s upgrade
```

will list available updates without actually installing.

First command updates package index files before simulated (thus -s) upgrade is done. "-s" will do a simulated upgrade showing packets that would be installed but will not actually install anything.

On the contrary "-u" instead of "-s" would actually install after confirmation.

Comment: The simulate option can be triggered with any of `-s, --simulate, --just-print, --dry-run, --recon, --no-act`, recon and dry-run are my personal favorites.

Answer (score 12):

Take a look at package "apticron":

apticron - Simple tool to mail about pending package updates

> Apticron is a simple script which sends daily emails about pending package updates such as security updates, properly handling packages on hold both by dselect and aptitude.

https://packages.debian.org/buster/apticron

Comment: Your link is broken...

Answer (score 10):

I needed full version information on possible upgrades, so I used a modification of jasonwryan's answer:

```
apt-get -V -u upgrade
```

It's simple and IMO reasonably formatted output.

Answer (score 5):

```
apt-get update > /dev/null && apt-get --just-print upgrade | grep "Inst "
```

is the most simple for cron emails; there is no user iteration, and if there are no updates there is no output.

Answer (score 4):

Just filter the output of

```
apt-get update && apt-get -s -V -u upgrade
```

to have only the preferred information in your log.

Most likely, you'll need the beautiful part after the line

> ...
>
> The following packages will be upgraded:
>
> ...

that has few spaces in the beginning.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site. As it stands, your answer is basically a rehash of existing ones and so does not add anything new. You could improve it by, for example, explaining how to filter the output, adding an explanation of what the various switches do etc.

Answer (score 3):

Jet another on-liner,
inspired by [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/75791/84379):

```sh
function a { read input;dpkg -l ${input} | grep " ${input} " | awk '{$1=$2=$3=$4="";print $0}' | sed 's/^ *//';unset input;};{ apt-get --just-print upgrade 2>&1 | perl -ne 'if (/Inst\s([\w,\-,\d,\.,~,:,\+]+)\s\[([\w,\-,\d,\.,~,:,\+]+)\]\s\(([\w,\-,\d,\.,~,:,\+]+)\)? /i) {print "$1 (\e[1;34m$2\e[0m -> \e[1;32m$3\e[0m)\n"}';} | while read -r line; do echo -en "$line $(echo $line | awk '{print $1}' | a )\n"; done;
```

The output looks like this (colored):

```
locales (2.13-38+deb7u7 -> 2.13-38+deb7u8) Embedded GNU C Library: National Language (locale) data [support]
linux-headers-3.2.0-4-amd64 (3.2.65-1+deb7u1 -> 3.2.65-1+deb7u2) Header files for Linux 3.2.0-4-amd64
linux-headers-3.2.0-4-common (3.2.65-1+deb7u1 -> 3.2.65-1+deb7u2) Common header files for Linux 3.2.0-4
sudo (1.8.5p2-1+nmu1 -> 1.8.5p2-1+nmu2) Provide limited super user privileges to specific users
```

If you dont want the short description use this one:

```sh
{ apt-get --just-print upgrade 2>&1 | perl -ne 'if (/Inst\s([\w,\-,\d,\.,~,:,\+]+)\s\[([\w,\-,\d,\.,~,:,\+]+)\]\s\(([\w,\-,\d,\.,~,:,\+]+)\)? /i) {print "$1 (\e[1;34m$2\e[0m -> \e[1;32m$3\e[0m)\n"}';} | while read -r line; do echo -en "$line\n"; done;
```

Output:

```
locales (2.13-38+deb7u7 -> 2.13-38+deb7u8)
linux-headers-3.2.0-4-amd64 (3.2.65-1+deb7u1 -> 3.2.65-1+deb7u2)
linux-headers-3.2.0-4-common (3.2.65-1+deb7u1 -> 3.2.65-1+deb7u2)
sudo (1.8.5p2-1+nmu1 -> 1.8.5p2-1+nmu2)
```

Comment: The one liner is fantastic, except it doesn't output the description of some packages.

Answer (score 3):

`apt-check` is probably the most efficient scripting method.

```
/usr/lib/update-notifier/apt-check 2>&1 | cut -d ';' -f 1
```

A very small modification shows you only the security updates.

```
/usr/lib/update-notifier/apt-check 2>&1 | cut -d ';' -f 2
```

Answer (score 3):

I like to use this:

```
apt-get -qq update && apt-get -qq -s upgrade
```

You get an output like this one:

```
Inst linux-base [3.5] (4.5~deb8u1 Debian-Security:8/oldstable [all])
Conf linux-base (4.5~deb8u1 Debian-Security:8/oldstable [all])
```

if there are available updates, and none if there isn't. This way you can simply couple it with a monitoring solution.

Answer (score 2):

After writing warning to @jasonwryan's answer, I want to provide my own solution:

```
apt-get dist-upgrade --assume-no
```

Unfortunately, this one doesn't work with debian wheezy and I had to check some lxc containers which are still not upgraded. This form will always work:

```
apt-get dist-upgrade </dev/null
```

Finally, I also wanted to reformat the output. I chose to change the call again (using `--dry-run` but ignoring all additional output) because it feels more safe:

```
apt-get --dry-run dist-upgrade | awk '
BEGIN{p=0}
/^The/{p=1;t=$0}
/no longer required/{p=0}
#optional: /been kept back/{p=0}
p && t{print t;t=""}
/^  / && p{print $0}
'
```

Returns:

```
The following packages have been kept back:
  iproute
The following packages will be upgraded:
  unzip
```

Answer (score 2):

There's the [`apt-show-versions`](http://alioth.debian.org/projects/pkg-asv/) tool.  To show available updates run:

```
apt-show-versions -u
```

Answer (score 1):

As a variation I use the following:

```
apt-get -V -s dist-upgrade \
    |grep -E "^   .*=>.*" \
    |awk 'BEGIN {
        ul=sprintf("%*s",40,""); gsub(/ /,"-",ul);
        printf "%-30s %-30s %-30s\n", "Package", "Installed", "Available";
        printf "%-30.30s %-30.30s %-30.30s\n", ul, ul, ul;
     }
     {
        printf "%-30s %-30s %-30s\n",
               $1,
               substr($2,2),
               substr($4,1,length($4)-1)
     }'
```

Stick it into a script named `apt-updates` and you can then call `apt-updates` to get a listing of all updates regardless of user.

You still do need to call `apt-get update` with privileged access.

Comment: output only shows the package name (first column), second column always prints "=" and third column is always empty. I'm on Mint.