# How to tell from which source the update is coming from (apt-get)

Tags: apt, upgrade, ppa

As usual, every time I update I'm getting a list with which programs received an update.
I also have a few PPA sources that are active.

I would like to know which update came from which source.

I'm using Mint, but I would prefer to do so from shell so this is relevant for all distributions using `apt-get`

Comment: `apt-get -s upgrade` would show you approximately where the packages are coming from.

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://superuser.com/questions/106794/how-to-tell-from-what-ubuntu-or-debian-repository-a-package-comes) thread says you can run `apt-cache policy <package name>`. With this and `aptitude -F%p --disable-columns search ~U` from [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/19472/103329), you can easily put together a small shell script to check and print for each package that will be upgraded,

```
aptitude -F%p --disable-columns search ~U | xargs apt-cache policy
```

Works perfectly for me on Trisquel, if you add that to your ~/.bashrc as an alias, for example

```
alias apt-wat='aptitude -F%p --disable-columns search ~U | xargs apt-cache policy'
```

You've got a bretty cewl command, shame it prints way too much.

or if you want to see where each package you have installed came from with `dpkg -l`, something like

```
dpkg -l | awk '{print $2}' | xargs apt-cache policy
```